# Maven: Failed to execute goal on project

Tags: xml, maven, aurelia, mvn-repo

I am about to connect my project in [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io/) with my friend's backend built with [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) but I met a problem when I run:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

in the project directory. I've never used Maven before.

Error description:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Projekt: Could not resolve
dependencies for project {project_name}:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to
find hibernate-annotations:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.0.GA in
http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release was cached in
the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
update interval of com.springsource.repository.bundles.release has
elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>***</groupId>
<artifactId>Projekt</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I googled a bit and try to run `mvn clean install` or delete /.m2 - it didn't help at all. If that is important, he uses Windows 10 and I try to run it with Ubuntu. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It looks like you are using a placeholder in your pom file, please, could you post your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Sharing the pom.xml content should help here @Marta

Comment: The dependency `hibernate-annotations:hibernate-annotations:3.3.0.GA` simply does not exists. Those are the wrong coordinates. http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.hibernate%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-annotations%22

Comment: But this works fine on W10.

Comment: you need to add the maven repository where it actually exists to your pom file or your settings file: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/

Comment: @anders ok! But how?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users?_sscc=t

Comment: I did it and now I get this error: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Projekt: Could not resolve dependencies for project ***:Projekt:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact hibernate-annotations:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.0.GA in repo1 (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases) -> [Help 1]'`
This is strange, because I found this package here... [https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.3.0.ga/]

Comment: hibernate annotations are included in hibernate core since v3.5 so you don't need the dep to hibernate-annotations